# Method onLocationChanged() is not getting a different location

Tags: android, gps, location

```
    package com.example.pointkeeper;
        import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.Criteria;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util

    public class ServicePointKeeper extends Service implements LocationListener{

    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    private LocationManager lm;
    ArrayList<Point> pt;
    Point p;
    private Context context;
    private Location loc;
    private final static long TEMPO_DE_ATUALIZACAO = 1 * 60 * 1000 ;

    private final static float DISTANCIA_DE_ATUALIZACAO = 1 ;

    public void setGPS(){

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy( Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE );
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
        String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        if ( provider == null ) {
            Log.d("SistemaGPS.ativar", "Nenhum provedor encontrado.");
        } else {
            Log.d("SistemaGPS.ativar", "Provedor utilizado: " + provider);

            //lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, TEMPO_DE_ATUALIZACAO, DISTANCIA_DE_ATUALIZACAO , this);
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, TEMPO_DE_ATUALIZACAO, DISTANCIA_DE_ATUALIZACAO , this);
        }
    }

    public void updateList(){
        p.setLatitude(loc.getLatitude());
        p.setLongitude(loc.getLongitude());
        pt.add(p);
    }


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loc = location;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + "Long: " + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            updateList();

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }       

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Serviço iniciado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.loc = null;
        pt = new ArrayList<Point>();
        p = new Point();
        lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        setGPS();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "GPS setado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Serviço parado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + latitude + "Long: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowPoints.class);
        it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelableArrayList("points", pt);
        it.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(it);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



}
```

So, in this code, my intention is to save a list of Points in an ArrayList of Points that will be use later. But all the points (latitude and longitude) have the same value, once i have the first value, all the others values are the same, its seems like onLocationChanged is never called.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sending different longitude latitude values from emulator control ?because otherwise it will only give you same values which is your last know location.As When testing on emulator you have to pass manual values each time to call onLocationChange method.

Comment: I'm testing in my nexus 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a global point p that you're overwriting every call to updateList.  Since you aren't creating a new point ever, this overwrites the old values.  That means every element in your list will always have the most recent values, rather than the value at that time.

Also, why are you using class variables everywhere rather than passing parameters to functions?  I have a feeling you don't understand Java or references very well.

Edit:

Here's what your code should look like, with locals used correctly:

```
package com.example.pointkeeper;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util

public class ServicePointKeeper extends Service implements LocationListener{

private LocationManager lm;
ArrayList<Point> pt;
private final static long TEMPO_DE_ATUALIZACAO = 1 * 60 * 1000 ;

private final static float DISTANCIA_DE_ATUALIZACAO = 1 ;

public void setGPS(){

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy( Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE );
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
    String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    if ( provider == null ) {
        Log.d("SistemaGPS.ativar", "Nenhum provedor encontrado.");
    } else {
        Log.d("SistemaGPS.ativar", "Provedor utilizado: " + provider);

        //lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, TEMPO_DE_ATUALIZACAO, DISTANCIA_DE_ATUALIZACAO , this);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, TEMPO_DE_ATUALIZACAO, DISTANCIA_DE_ATUALIZACAO , this);
    }
}

public void updateList(Location loc){
    Point p = new Point();
    p.setLatitude(loc.getLatitude());
    p.setLongitude(loc.getLongitude());
    pt.add(p);
}


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + "Long: " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        updateList(location);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }       

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Serviço iniciado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    pt = new ArrayList<Point>();
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    setGPS();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "GPS setado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Serviço parado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + latitude + "Long: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowPoints.class);
    it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelableArrayList("points", pt);
    it.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(it);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: So, my global point p, should have the new geolocations, and then update the list, but what im saying is that the point p, always have the same value.

where i should use references?

Comment: No, p shouldn't be global at all.  It should be local.  The fact that p is global is your problem.  Loc, latitude, and longitude should also not be globals.  Your problem is you don't know when to use a global and when to use a local, and how the choice effects references.

Comment: Check my edited comment for what your code should look like-  loc, p, latitude, and longitude no longer class level variables, and a new point allocated for each update.

Comment: Now i understand and see what you said, and im feel bad. haha
Now, the app just work fine. Thanks man, i will never made a mistake like this anymore. Thanks